# Bash redirect and stdin

Tags: linux, bash

I'm hoping this is a quick question for a guru.
I have the following command which works great from the command line:

```
 src/protected/yiic shell src/index.php <<< createmvp < /dev/tty
```

This command executes the yiic bash script and passes it the arguments shell and src/index.php.

The first <<< passes the argument createmvp to the terminal prompt which is displayed when yiic shell src/index.php is run on it's own.

The second < then allows std in to be returned to the application.

However when I run this inside a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
src/protected/yiic shell src/index.php <<< createmvp < /dev/tty
```

The script doesn't pass createmvp into the shell.
If I remove the < /dev/tty bit passing createmvp works, but then recapture the terminal obviously doesn't. Nothing I seem to do works.

```
while(!isset($input))
{
    $input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    if(!$input)
        echo "$configVar can not be NULL";
}
```

Any ideas, on how to make this work as it does from the command line?

Thanks in advance

Alan

Comment: I am not in linux right now, but I think you have to pass the 2 first arguments with quotes;
src/protected/yiic "shell src/index.php" <<< createmvp < /dev/tty

Comment: That launches the shell but does pass createmvp into the application. Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Comment: What if you move the input redirection to the beginning of the line?  IIRC it's legal to put it anywhere:::::::::::::  `< /dev/tty src/protected/yiic shell src/index.php <<< createmvp`

Comment: @Wug this didn't work. This successfully passed createmvp into the application but didn't give me the terminal prompt back ( all inputs were null in the while loop ). Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Answer (score 2):

`(echo createmvp; cat /dev/tty) | src/protected/yiic shell src/index.php`

I think that the reason `<<< createmvp < /dev/tty` doesn't work is because both `<<<` and `<` are ways to specify the source for standard in and you can't do both. `<<<` takes a string as an argument and passes it to stdin whereas `<` takes a file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use eval:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="src/protected/yiic shell src/index.php <<< createmvp < /dev/tty"
eval $cmd
```

Comment: This opens the yiic shell but doesn't pass createmvp into it. Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Comment: so, one of the solutions passes createmvp into yiic shell, and the other doesn't...either a writing mistake or I really don't understand what you want to achieve :P

Comment: So yiic is the program and shell src/index.php are the arguments. yiic opens a shell which accepts user input. By doing <<< createmvp I can pipe that into the shell and it runs that command. createmvp runs a php script, which then waits for user input on STDIN, but this is always null when the command is run via a bash script. It works perfectly when ran from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To exit the script as soon as `yiic` processes the `exit` command itself, a `trap` on exit can be used for the `yiic` subshell:

```
# small addition to cpugeniusmv's answer
(echo createmvp; cat /dev/tty) | 
    (trap 'kill 0' EXIT; src/protected/yiic shell src/index.php)
```